# code is skipping userform show and button click

Tags: button, userform, buttonclick

I have a code that when excel opens a userform automatically shows and then allows me to click a button. When I click the button it calls a Main sub to run that code.
In the Main sub I also want another userforms (with a frame, label and button) to popup/show and have the Main Sub code pause until a button is clicked on the new userform.
However the code seems to skip the 2nd userform, it briefly appears as blank, but disappears as the Main sub continues to run to the end.
The code association with the userform (named Notification1) is:

```
Dim ContDataConvButton As Boolean

Private Sub Notification1_Initialize() 

Me.ContDataConvButton = False
Do While Me.ContDataConvButton = False 
   'do nothing 
Loop 
End Sub 
    
Private Sub Notification1_Activate() 
End Sub 
    
Private Sub Cont_data_conv_button_Click() 
  Me.ContDataConvButton = True 
  Unload Me 
End Sub
```

The code in the Main Sub is:

```
Sub Main()
'code ....
Notification1.show(false) 'I have set it to vbmodeless so that the user can make any changes to the 
sheet before clicking the button to continue. Once the button is clicked I would like to return to this 
point back in the Main Sub.
```

Appreciate any advice you can provide to solve this issue.
Regards,
Glenn

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I just needed to place a DoEvents statement in the Do While Loop